# using jquery in iframe child to check checkboxes by name

Tags: jquery, iframe, checkbox, parent-child

I have an iframe (same domain) that has a bunch of checkboxes on it.
I'd like to have javascript run from the parent page and mark checkboxes in the child based on the name of the checkboxes (they have different values - but I'd like to check them all).  The iframe's id and its name are both AppBody.  All the checkboxes I care about are named dow0.

Updated to include where I stand now as far as digging down to the checkboxes.

```js
alert("start");
var iframe = document.getElementById("AppBody");
var doc = iframe.contentWindow.document;
var widgets= doc.getElementById("widgets");
var detail= widgets.getElementById("Detail");

var checkboxes = doc.getElementsByName("dow0");
alert(checkboxes.length);
    for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
         checkboxes[i].checked = true;
   }
```

Comment: I used to play around with javascript quite a bit but havent in a few years.  Honestly I've tried searching around to see if I can find something similar and not had much luck.

Comment: So you haven't tried anything on your own yet?  You're not likely to get answers if people get the idea that you're not willing to participate in discovering your own solutions.  If you have made some attempts, then post the relevant code (meaning, take some effort to remove the irrelevant code rather than just pasting all of it) and direct your questions to specifics.

Comment: updated with what I've tried

Comment: Ok.  The next thing is that you are using javascript here, not jquery, and have jquery tagged.  Are you using jquery at all, or just javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although there isn't any jQuery in your code, I'm going to assume that you are using jQuery, since you have your question tagged as such and don't have a javascript tag.

First, add `class="dow0"` to each of your elements with that name.  Classes are easier to work with than names in jQuery.  Then:

```
$('.dow0').prop('checked', true);
```

will check all of the checkboxes with the class `dow0`.  This assumes that you don't have any other checkboxes with the same class name outside of your iframe.  If that's not so, you can put in a more restrictive selector:

```
$('#AppBody .dow0').prop('checked', true);
```

This is saying to set the `checked` property to `true` in any element with the class `dow0` that is contained in the element with id `AppBody`.